# Не получается обратиться к тегу через CSS

Tags: html, css

Не могу понять в чём проблема, не получается подключить стили к самому footer__col--second. При этом к элементам получилось стили подключить. В чём моя ошибка ?

```css
.footer__col--second {
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}

.second_item {
  display: flex;
}

.second_item a {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.second_item p {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.second__inner {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer__col--second">
  <h1 class="footer__title">blogs</h1>
  <div class="second_item">
    <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/footer/Clip-1.png" alt=""></a>
    <div class="second__inner">
      <p> LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING</p>
      <time> Jan 9, 2016</time>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нет проблемы. Стили подключаются (красная заливка и черный бордер)

Comment: Не работает, все стили корректно отображаются а этот нет. Не знаю может проблема в остальном коде, у меня там несколько колон, и с ними всё нормально а с этим ерунда какая то.

Comment: Значит, "проблема в остальном коде".  Возможно, стили перебиваются. Я же не просто так написал - создал файлы, проверил. Да и после Вашей правки в вопросе появилась кнопка "Выполнить код", проверьте сами